# Open source reporting library for Java with drill down functionalities

Tags: java, reporting

I am developing a stand alone desktop application using Java. I want to find a good reporting module for java with drill down capabilities so user can switch between reports. I have used libraries like RDLC reporting in .Net and something similar is highly appreciated. Any suggestions and opinions are warmly welcome.

Answer (score 1):

[Jasper Reports](http://jasperforge.org/projects/jasperreports). They also provide [sample](http://jasperforge.org/uploads/publish/jasperreportswebsite/trunk/samples.html) reports (their *HyperLink* report example is rather simplistic though).

There also is GUI designer for report templates called [iReport](http://jasperforge.org/projects/ireport).

Answer (score 0):

How about [Eclipse BIRT](http://www.eclipse.org/birt/phoenix/).

BIRT is an Eclipse-based open source reporting system for web applications, especially those based on Java and Java EE. BIRT has two main components: a report designer based on Eclipse, and a runtime component that you can add to your app server. BIRT also offers a charting engine that lets you add charts to your own application.